# Accessing external SVG graphics with the USE tag

Tags: svg

Dear Stack Overflow,

I am trying to reference individual SVG graphics which reside in different SVG files
via the  tag and ID numbers in a master HTML5 page.

I want to be able to put onclicks on the use tags in the HTML page in order to 
make a multiple choice quiz (and then keep a score which I know how to do),
The graphics are going to be bulky. Therefore, these need to be in an external svg files.

Here however, I have used a simple rectangle to make my question easier to 
follow

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<svg>  
<use xlink:href="LINK.svg#link" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is My SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="link">
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="fill:red"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

This works exactly the way I want it to in Firefox and Opera. 
However, it does not work in Chrome or Safari. Not sure about Internet Explorer

Is there an alternative method that will allow me external access to the 
SVG data, and scripting from the main HTML page (because I want can keep a score
over multiple SVG elements)

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91237

Answer (score 0):

You could access your SVG by using an `<object>` tag. [This link](https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html) shows you how to script from html to SVG and vice versa.

Comment: This i works to an extent. However, I want to insert more than one external graphic into the 'picture frame' and then alter the dimensions and placement of the 'minisvgs' to make one big picture.I also want to put a separate onclick, onmouseovers and css hovers onto each 'minisvg'

Comment: So what's stopping you? Since you're using an object tag you'll have to do all the onclick, onmouseover and css hovers in the svg objects is there any other issue?